# Django/DRF endpoint to serve SVG static files

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm building an API with Django and Django Rest Framework. I'm stuck in building an endpoint to serve a collection of SVG files (some fun emojis :P).

These SVG files aren't stored in the DB (hence I don't have a `Django Model` for them), instead they are in the project's `static` folder where dey have their own sub-folder:

```
 | project
 | + static
 | | + assets
 | | | + emojis
 | | | | | smile.svg
 | | | | | laugh.svg
 | | | | | etc...
```

I have tried different approaches but I'm not sure.
One was the following view:

```
# Python
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
# Django
from django.http import HttpResponse


def list_emojis(request):

    emojis_path = 'project/static/assets/emojis/'

    emojis = [f for f in listdir(emojis_path) if isfile(join(emojis_path, f))]
    ret = []
    for emoji in emojis:
        ret.append(open(emojis_path+emoji, 'r'))
    return HttpResponse(ret, content_type='multipart/form-data')
```

This is returning a binary file downloaded (when I go to the URL with my browser) which looks like this:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='project/static/assets/emojis/094-user.svg' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'><_io.TextIOWrapper name='project/static/assets/emojis/059-sad-11.svg' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'><_io.TextIOWrapper name='project/static/assets/emojis/006-shooting-star.svg' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'><_io.TextIOWrapper name='project/static/assets/emojis/120-briefcase.svg' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'><_io.TextIOWrapper name='project/static/assets/emojis/016-monkey.svg' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'><_io.TextIOWrapper name='project/static/assets/emojis/185-tongue.svg' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

I have never returned files from an API before.
What would be the right approach with Django Rest Framework? Take into account that these are almost 200 SVGs (4kb each of them).

Comment: Just wanted to understand the case better. So we are required to share the location of file or the content of file.

Comment: The file(s) itself. Send the SVGs to the frontend (incoming request in the view)

Comment: And all the svgs should be embedded in single file?

Comment: no, one file per SVG. It should be a response of 200 svgs